# using multiple commands when creating keyboard shortcut via gui

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

I am trying to run multiple bash scripts with a keyboard command. Can someone explain why they dont both run? each script runs if I make each one its own shortcut,although the first script is occasionally strange.

```
/bin/bash /home/king/Scripts/misc/my_keyboard off ; /bin/bash /home/king/Scripts/rotate_desktop left
```

Could it have something to do with the background redirection of onboard in the first script? Is it never getting to the second script because of that?

script: my_keyboard

```
#!/bin/bash  

case "$1" in
    on)
    export DISPLAY=:0
        xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
    killall -q onboard 
    ;;
    off)
    onboard &> /dev/null 2>&1
    export DISPLAY=:0
    xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
    ;;
esac
```